# Android Studio, No Main Activity Setup Page

Tags: java, android, android-studio, operating-system

Lately, after updating Android Studio, when I create a new project, name the Application, it jumps right to FINISH, with NEXT grayed out, and does not go to the MAIN ACTIVITY setup page for renaming the Main Activity. It offers only the one setup page for the APPLICATION.  Does anyone know if this is caused by the new update, or have I done something on my end to cause this. I suppose I could just continue, as is, and just go in an rename the MAIN ACTIVITY, but I would rather not have to do this with each project.  Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2):

Create New Project without Activity. Then right click on package name, click New -> Activity -> and choose your prefered activity. You will be able set Activity Name, layout name etc.
It is not elegant , but only one solution which I found.

Comment: Much, MUCH appreciated.  Makes great sense.  Actually, just late yesterday and before getting your solution, I created a project with its default main, then, added a New Activity, setting the new one for LAUNCH, with plans to delete the default one.  But I did not know if that could create problems for running the App.  Thanks, again, for your enormous help with this.